# Adding 2 mysql queries that has same no of fields but from diff tables

Tags: php

Below is my code to add the two different query results into one. This is working fine when both the queries have same no.of rows.

eg:

```
row1 = 1 2 3 (Query1)

row2 = 3 5 5 (Query2)

o/p:    4 7 8
```

Let's say, I have few rows which are not exactly matched with first query.

eg:

```
row1 =  1      2       3      2   (Query1)

row2 =  3    empty empty      5   (Query2)

o/p :   4      2       3      7   (I want the o/p to be like this)
```

empty means there is no data from the second query.

In my while, && working fine when the 2 queries have same no.of rows.

```
while (($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs1)) && ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2)))
{


$strHtml .= "<tr>";

$strHtml .= "<td align=center colspan=3>".($row1['Calls']+$row2['Calls'])."</td>";
$strHtml .= "<td align=center colspan=3>".($row1['actual_duration(min)A']+$row2['actual_duration(min)A'])."</td>";
$strHtml .= "<td align=center colspan=3>".($row1['call_usage']+$row2['call_usage'])."</td>";
$strHtml .= "<td align=center colspan=3>".($row1['disconnection_charge']+$row2['disconnection_charge'])."</td>";
$strHtml .= "<td align=center colspan=3>".($row1['total_revenue']+$row2['total_revenue'])."</td>";

$strHtml .= "</tr>";

}
```

Is the while loop i am using correct or there is any other better solution for this?

please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered doing a single outer join instead of two simple "selects"?

Comment: I am not too sure how to do that as I am new learner. Can u give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it all in the SQL query using an OUTER JOIN as @paulsm4 suggests, you might try changing your while to an ||.  Then check $row1 and $row2 inside the loop to see if they are empty and calculate your sums accordingly.  Is that sufficient?  I can put together code if you like...

Comment: Hi Alan, I tried using || but not getting the desired result(i mean not summing the 2 query results) and displaying separately. If u can follow my above code and provide me the working code, would be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could compute all db-side and render a simpler result:

```
select ifnull(a,0)+ifnull(c,0), ifnull(b,0)+ifnull(d,0) from (select a, b from table1) as x, (select c, d from table2) as y
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few different ways you can solve this, some in mysql and some in php. I don't know which one you prefer, so I'll list a couple.

mysql solution #1:
Set the default value of your columns to 0, so you will never get empty results. (You'll get 0 instead, and then the addition will work fine)

mysql solution #2:
You can use `IFNULL` as @Josh suggested, or `COALESCE` will also work.

php solution #1:
loop through your data, and assign empty values to 0.

```
foreach($row1 as &$value) {
    if(empty($value)) { $value = 0; }
}
unset($value);

foreach($row2 as &$value) {
   if(empty($value)) { $value = 0; }
}
unset($value);
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Can u tell me how do i set a column to default value 0 ? As I have multiple tables and wrote inner joins to retrieve the data, I am bit confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this mysql command `ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER column SET DEFAULT 0` (Where my_table is the name of your table, and column is the name of the field you want to change.) When you set a default value, every time a record gets inserted, the value of that field will be set to the default value unless you specify otherwise. Since you would be setting it to 0, you can add without any problems.

Comment: Yes.You are correct but that is not what i wanted. Let me clarify u once again. Let's say I have a column called 'country_name', 'country_code' and 'no_of_calls' in both the queries. If the 'no_of_calls' from query1 is '10' for the 'country_name' USA and 'country_code' 1 and '20' for the 'country_name' India and 'country_code' 91 and 'no_of_calls' from query2 is '15' for the 'country_name' USA and 'country_code' 1. Now i want the o/p to be 'country_name' USA 'country_code' 1 and 'no_of_call' 25 and 'country_name' India 'country_code' 91 and 'no_of_call' 20. HOpe u understand my question.